# One big query or lots of smaller queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need a bit of advice when it comes to making efficient use of database resource.

At the moment, I'm building an ordering system that takes an uploaded file, and runs through that file adding each line to an order.

At the same time this is done, the app checks that the product code requested is available to sell to that customer.

Given that the file can contain upwards of 200 lines (and thus that many requests to the database to check), I'm eager to know if, it's more efficient to make a single request to the database for all the product codes available, and then run the check against that list, even though there will be roughly 2000 codes in that list.

So, either 200 sequential one result requests, or a single 2000 result request.

The site will be handling about 130 uploads within a 4-5 hour period, and must traverse a VPN from Azure to our database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will definitely be more efficient to make a single query that gets 2000 rows than to make 200 queries that gets a single row. For the single row queries the actual data would be a minor part of the traffic, it would be mostly overhead.

Another alternative would be to put that check in the query that adds the line to the order, that way you don't need a separate query to check the product first. If the product can't be sold to the customer the query would simply not insert any record, and it can return the number of records added so that the calling code can determine if the line was added or not.

Example:

```
create procedure AddOrderLine
  @OrderId int,
  @ProductId int,
  @Quantity int
as

set nocount on

insert into OrderLines (OrderId, ProductId, Quantity)
select
  o.OrderId,
  @ProductId,
  @Quantity
from
  Orders o
  inner join AllowedProducts a on a.CustomerId = o.CustomerId and a.ProductId = @ProductId
where
  OrderId = @OrderId

return @@rowcount
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like another case of [Permature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) (tam tam taaaaam).

You don't know that you have a problem, and yet you're trying to solve it. The first thing you should see is if there's a real performance problem here. My guess is - there isn't. You're going to read 2000 records and write 200 records once every few minutes. That's really not something to worry about.

But don't take my word for it, try it out. See how long it takes you to load those 2000 records and write those 200 records. If there's a problem, try to optimize.

By the way, optimizing this by breaking the request into 200 smaller requests is unlikely to work. Let's cross this bridge when you get there.